# Dynamically set push notification status when using Urban Airship

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I have set up my objective C app with [Urban Airship](https://www.urbanairship.com/) for push notifications and can receive them just fine. But in my app the user should be able to remove these notifications, i.e. the user don't want to receive any more push messages. I just can't figure out how to turn it off.

**I am aware that the user can disable notifications in settings for the app in device settings, but this is not a desirable solution in this particular case. The app should still be *allowed* to receive notifications.**

I found some methods to call and variables to set but nothing helps. When I try to remove my registration to get notifications I call this:

```
[UAirship push].allowUnregisteringUserNotificationTypes = YES;
[UAirship push].userPushNotificationsEnabled = NO;
[UAirship push].backgroundPushNotificationsEnabled = NO;
[[UAirship push] setUserNotificationTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeNone)];
[[UAirship push] updateRegistration];
```

Anyone knows it this is actually at all possible, or do I have to remove differently?

Comment: are you using third party frameworks to stop notification ..whats is `UAirship` ?

Comment: @vaibhav I'm using a third party framework called Urban Airship which handles push notifications instead of Apple's APNS servers. So I set up Urban Airship to be able to send push notifications to my app through their servers. But I can't turn it off, even though the code presented above indicates that it should be possible.

Comment: @ClookWise my confusion here infect all the third party pushnotification like `GCM` or `UAirship` syncd with APN so have you tried to disabling notification from regular way (APN) ..

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to set `requireSettingsAppToDisableUserNotifications` to be able to disable user notifications.

We had to protect against disabling notifications due to a bug introduced in iOS 8 where if you disable notifications they are unable to enabled again without a restart (Radar #17878212). Instead, we recommend you only allow enabling notifications within the app, then provide a [link to the settings](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios.html#enabling-user-notifications) for your users to easily disable them. Its not ideal but it avoids the bug.

It looks like its finally fixed in iOS 10, so our SDK 8.0.0 for iOS 10 support will allow disabling types without any extra flags or hassle.

Answer (score 0):

simply use code below:

```
// use this for start recieving notification (enable)


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

// use this for stop recieving notification (disable)

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```